# AVPlayerItem videoComposition freeze IOS8

Tags: ios8, avplayer, freeze, avmutablecomposition

I am playing a AVMutableVideoComposition with AVPlayer and since IOS8 everything was perfectly fine.
But now the video start playing and after 4 or 5 seconds it stop ,like buffering or something like that, the sound keeps playing and when the video ends the AVPlayer loops and play it fine without stops.

I have no clue for fixing this issue.

Any help would be appreciate,

Thank you

Comment: I am getting same issue.May be its issue with IOS 8.
Still I am not get any solution.....!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same issue, but I got the solution.

You should play after playerItem's status is changed to .ReadyToPlay.

I also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402674/weird-behaviour-of-avmutablecomposition-freezing-while-using-avmutablevideocompo/33369604#33369604), that issue is similar to your issue.

Please see as below.

```
func startVideoPlayer() {
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.composition!)
    playerItem.videoComposition = self.videoComposition!

    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .None

    videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    videoPlayerLayer!.frame = self.bounds

    /* add playerItem's observer */
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.status", options: .New, context: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerItem);

    self.layer.addSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath != nil && keyPath! == "player.currentItem.status" {
        if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
            if AVPlayerStatus(rawValue: newValue as! Int) == .ReadyToPlay {
                playVideo() /* play after status is changed to .ReadyToPlay */
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}    

func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    let playerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    playerItem.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)

    playVideo()
} 

func playVideo() {
    videoPlayerLayer?.player!.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here, don't know if it can be count like an answer but anyway, just use
 `[AVPlayer seekToTime:AVPlayer.currentItem.duration];` to make first loop by yourself and to avoid AVPlayer stop. That's only way that i found.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and i solved it this way ..
Instead of applying videoComposition to AVPlayerItem directly .. i exported my video using **AVAssetExportSession** to apply videoComposition, which in turn gives me a Url with a video having all my videoComposition applied and now i can use this contentURL to play video on AVPlayer..
This works like a charm ..
Exporting video will take time but as now rendering video composition is not happening on the go, it will work smoothly..

Following code can be used to export video ..

```
AVAssetExportSession *export = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPreset1280x720];

export.videoComposition = videoComposition;
export.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSTemporaryDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSUUID new].UUIDString] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"MOV"]];
export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
export.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

[export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  if (export.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted) {

    completionHander(export.outputURL, nil);

  } else {

    completionHander(nil, export.error);

  }
});
}];
```